# load the content of html file into the div using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, load

I am a beginner. The problem I am dealing with is probably very simple to solve ;) I am working on a web page where the text content is loaded from external html files into the div. This is done when a user clicks on a menu item.

This is my code html :

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
          <div>
                      <ul>      
                          <li><a id="teachers" href="#" name="teachers" onclick="getdata()">
                            Teachers
                          </li> 
                        </ul>
          </div>

          <div id="page"  name="" >
            bla bla bla ...
          </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my code ajax:

```
var _xhr;

function getdata(){

    _xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
    _xhr.onreadystatechange=callback;
    _xhr.open("POST", "teachers.html", true);
    _xhr.send();

    function callback(){
        var _target = document.getElementById("page");
        _target.innerHTML=_xhr.responseText;
    }

}
```

I would like to load the html file (teachers.html) into the div (id="page") when I click on the link (Teachers)

Please could someone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to tell us what the problem is so we can provide more info. Does it throw an error? Never calls the callback? Can't find the element? responseText is empty?

Comment: yes @artm the responseText is empty

Comment: Have you tried `if (_xhr.readyState==4 && _xhr.status==200)`

Comment: Yes @artm the same problem

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: no @Barmar all is right but the it doesn't want to load the page

Comment: If you look in the Network tab of DevTools, do you see the AJAX response there?

Comment: Please tell me how can I use this Sir ?

Comment: you can simply change "_xhr.onreadystatechange=callback;" to "_xhr.onload=callback;"

Comment: Hello @dandavis . I tried it but ot doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

onreadystate fires multiple times. You need to wait for the readystate of 4 before reading the responseText

```
function callback(){
    if (_xhr.readyState===4) {
        var _target = document.getElementById("page");
        _target.innerHTML=_xhr.responseText;
    }
}
```

you probably should also check the status.

Comment: I tried this one, the same problem. Anyway thanks for your answer